# Category theory: do other examples of "resplendent" properties exist?

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples

Call a predicate $P$ defined on categories *resplendent* iff it satisfies the following condition: for all categories $\mathbf{D}$, if $P(\mathbf{D}),$ then for all categories $\mathbf{C}$, we have $P(\mathbf{D}^\mathbf{C}).$ Examples of resplendent predicates include: being terminal, being a setoid, being a preordered set, being a groupoid, being a truthvalue, being a category. Compare with the [periodic table](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28n%2Cr%29-category#the_periodic_table).

> **Question.** Do other examples of resplendent properties exist?

*Remark.* Resplendency makes sense for predicates defined on the objects of any self-enriched category.

Comment: TFAE? Don't abbreviate stuff. Stack Exchange has plenty of storage.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I usually don't use acronyms, but "the following are equivalent" is just so long-winded for such a basic construct. But perhaps you're right.

Comment: If you don't want to communicate with the widest audience, by all means, use acronyms. I'd never seen it, and I've been doing math a long time.

Comment: The second property always implies the first, so you're just asking for properties that are inherited by functor categories. There are all sorts of these, e.g. being abelian (really a property, not a structure!).

Comment: My 2 cents: if there are just two propositions simply spelling it out is simpler... "Call a predicate $P$ ""resplendent"" (...) when a category $\mathbf{D}$ satisfies $P$ iff $P(\mathbf{D^C}$ satisfies $P$ for all category $\mathbf{C}$" or something like that. (A third cent: I dislike this trend of putting random names on mathematical objects/properties, like all these "amicable" numbers or "betrothed" or "superabundant" or whatever. In what way is such a category "shining brilliantly"?)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, true, so there's clearly heaps of them. FWIW, I think that referring to this as the property of being "inherited by functor categories" is a bit dangerous, since it could be mistaken for the assertion: $P(\mathbf{D}) \wedge P(\mathbf{C}) \rightarrow P(\mathbf{D}^\mathbf{C}).$

Comment: @goblin: no, I don't think so. It's extremely rare for properties of $C$ to have anything to do with properties of $D^C$ (I can't think of any interesting examples off the top of my head).

Answer (score 1):

As long as we don't allow empty categories, the property "has at least $\kappa$-many objects" is resplendent for every cardinal $\kappa$.

Similarly, "has a non-well-orderable set of objects."

Comment: You make an interesting point (+1). Note that the collection of non-empty categories is canonically self-enriched, re: the remark at the end of my question.